# count unique values by category using excel formula

Tags: excel, formula

I have a database table with a set of category names in column A. think of it as category A, B, C, D, etc. then in column b I have numbers for each category. for a specific category, say category A, the related numbers are not unique and may occur in different frequencies.

now I have another table, a summary one and I want a formula to count unique numbers for each category from the database table and return it in front of the category name.
 I use excel 2010
for some reasons I do not want to use pivot table or macros

data is as below

A  10

A  10

A  20

A  15

B  25

B  25

B  25

B  30

B  empty(blank)

the desired results should be as this

A  3

B  2

thanks for help

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use a pivot table, but can you use SUMIF or COUNTIF or something similar? A sample of data and desired results would help a lot.

Comment: because the summary table has many columns that are filled by formulas and not all of them could be put in one single pivot table

Comment: Okay, I get what you are trying to do. It is basically a Group By with a count distinct on your second column. I don't have access to Excel right now but maybe someone else can help. If not I can maybe help on Monday, 5/13.

Comment: =SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20),B$2:B$20)>0))

Answer (score 0):

So an example of sumif() and countif().

But I am not sure what you really want as there are 4 categories of A, and 4 of B - unless some numbers must be ignored.

However, see:

[image]

Note, if the columns A & B only have the relevant information you can define the range as A:A, but if the range has to be limited then you need to use A1:A17.

Edit try:

[image]

Comment: I want a formula to return the number of unique values in column b for each category in column a, for example, the result should be 3 unique values for category A and 2 for category B (ignoring blank cells)

Answer (score 0):

you may try google sheet there has formula

COUNTUNIQUE(A1:C100, 100)

&

COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A1:A3, B1:B3, "<100", C1:C3, ">5")

Comment: This question is very clearly for Excel, though.

Answer (score -1):

The best way of doing these is to use Frequency:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$20=D2,B$2:B$20),B$2:B$20)>0))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Plz search on 'Count unique with a condition' for more information.